# Apply span style for color and span class for bold

Tags: html, css

How do I apply both a style for color, such as `<span style="color:#c00000">` and a class such as `<span class="Bold">` to some text? I've tried the example below, but I'm very new to CSS and don't quite understand yet how to apply both. In my example below, the color shows up but not the bold. Thanks for any help.

```
<span style="color:#c00000"class="Bold">Some text element</span>
```

Comment: The HTML shown is valid.  Have you created any CSS styles for the `.Bold` class?  Where is that?

Answer (score 2):

You can write all styles in `style` attribute by seperating with `;`

```
<span style="color:#c00000; font-weight:bold;">Some text element</span>
```

Or you can define a style for a class with css and use it from HTML

```
<html>
<style>
.myclass {
  color:#c00000;
  font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<span class="myclass">Some text element</span>
</html>
```

And still you can use `class` and `style` attributes.

And maybe you can learn more from [W3Schools CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) and [W3Schools html classes](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_classes.asp).

Comment: I used the top one, and that worked! Thank you. (I'm using this in Obsidian so it's just for a text element I want colored and bold)

Answer (score 0):

you have it correct but need to add css font_weight:bold to the .Bold class

```css
.Bold{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<span style="color:#c00000"class="Bold">Some text element</span><br>
<span style="color:#c00000">Some text element</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be appropriate to use HTML tags in this case to wrap around text that you want bold rather than to style it with CSS. Mark up using the `<b>` or `<strong>` to style the weight of the text and use inline styling if you are unable to add using a stylesheet as inlining styles are harder to override later on.

```
<b style="color:#000000;">Some text copy here</b>
```

More information on when to use p, span, div can be found on [W3Docs](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-not-to-wrap-the-contents-of-p-div-and-span-elements.html).